# CMake autodetect Visual Studio directory on windows

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cross-platform

Currently, in order to create static libs on windows, you manually have to specify where the Visual Studio directory is.

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_GNUtoMS=1 -DCMAKE_GNUtoMS_VCVARS="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" ..
```

Is there a way for CMake to automatically query for the location of Visual Studio? The `Windows-GNU.cmake` module seems to be able to query the registry for the location of the `lib.exe` executable, but still forces the user to manually specify it's location. An excerpt from cmake:

```
  find_program(CMAKE_GNUtoMS_VCVARS NAMES vcvars32.bat
    DOC "Visual Studio vcvars32.bat"
    PATHS
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\12.0\\Setup\\VC;ProductDir]/bin" #D
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\11.0\\Setup\\VC;ProductDir]/bin"
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\10.0\\Setup\\VC;ProductDir]/bin"
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\9.0\\Setup\\VC;ProductDir]/bin"
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\8.0\\Setup\\VC;ProductDir]/bin"
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\7.1\\Setup\\VC;ProductDir]/bin"
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\6.0\\Setup\\Microsoft Visual C++;ProductDir]/bin"
    )
```

The above is from cmake 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

If building a static library is your primary concern, have you tried setting

```
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
```

or similar (e.g. `add_library` with `STATIC`) to force static build?